# Statistical Analysis and Smoothing based on user ages

Tags: sql, statistics

I have a set of users in my system. Many of which are young users with regards to the age of their account.

I have then looked at a users event per day over the life time of the account (ie the event can occur on the 2nd day of their account existing then again on the 10th and so on all the way up to the life time of their account.)

What I am trying to do is look at the average occurrence of this event on a daily basis over all accounts, but need to take into consideration that I actually have many more young users (ie users which have not been around a long time).

I have tried a couple of statistical tricks, but am not 100% sure the best method to go about doing this.

Any point in the right direction would help.

Comment: You want to learn the ideas of survival analysis and censored observations.  The answer is too long for StackOverflow.  I would recommend the book "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel", which has two chapters on survival analysis.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I tried to find you book in the local book store but they did not have it. I will have to order it online - Thanks for the point in the right direction I think I have got a lot further in solving the problem now.

Comment: http://crossvalidated.com would be a good place to ask

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, I figured this out in the end. Will still be buying the book though.